# How can I separate the odd and even elements of list using recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, list

How can I separate the odd and even elements of list using recursion?

For example:

```
oddevenseparator([1]) => [[1], []]
oddevenseparator([2]) => [[], [2]]
oddevenseparator([1,2,3,4,5,6])=> [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify odd and even numbers just do a mod 2 (number%2), which gives you a remainder.

code may look something like this:

```
  def oddevenseparator(i: int, nums: List[int], ans: List[List[int]]):
      if(i>= len(nums)):
          return ans    
      if(nums[i]%2==0): 
          ans[1].append(nums[i])
          ans[0].remove(nums[i])
      return oddevenseparator(i+1,nums,ans)

  print(oddevenseparator(0,nums,[nums,[]]))
```